# Running time of Euclid's GCD algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to learn number theory for RSA cryptography by reading the CLR algorithms book. I was looking at exercise 31.2-5 which claims a bound of 1 + log<sub>Φ</sub>(b / gcd(a,b)).

The full question is:

If a > b >= 0, show that the invocation `EUCLID(a,b)` makes at most 1 + log<sub>Φ</sub>b  recursive calls. Improve this bound to 1 + log<sub>Φ</sub>(b / gcd(a,b)).

Does anyone know how to show this? There are already several other questions and answers to Euclid's algorithm on this site already but none of them seem to have this exact precise answer.

Comment: Are you having problems with the first or the second part of the task?

Comment: Also whish euclid algorithm is that - the one with division and remainder or the one with subtraction?

Comment: If memory serves, Knuth (volume 2?) has quite an extensive disclosure of the complexity of Euclid's GCD algorithm.

Comment: I took a look at the Knuth book and couldn't find a detailed mathematical argument about the exact question I am asking or similar one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the analysis of Euclid's algorithm by Donald Knuth, in *TAOCP* Vol.2 [p.356](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=OtLNKNVh1XoC&pg=PA356)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the first part. I am still working on the second

We know that the runtime of Euclid algorithm is a function of the number of steps involved (pg of the book)
Let k be the number of recursive steps needed. 
    Hence b >= F k+1 >= φ k -1 
    b >= φ k -1
Taking log to find k we have
    Log φ b >= k-1
     1 + Log φ b > = k 
Hence the run time is O (1 + Log φ b)

Answer (score 1):

1. Show that if `Euclid(a,b)` takes more than `N` steps, then
   `a>=F(n+1)` and `b>=F(n)`, where `F(i)` is the `i`th Fibonacci
   number. 
   This can easily be done by Induction.
2. Show that `F(n)` ≥ φ<sup>n-1</sup>, again by
       Induction.
3. Using results of Step 1 and 2, we have b ≥ `F(n)` ≥
       φ<sup>n-1</sup> 
    Taking logarithm on both sides,
       log<sub>φ</sub>b ≥ n-1. 
    Hence proved, n ≤ 1 +
       log<sub>φ</sub>b

The second part trivially follows.
No. of recursive calls in `EUCLID(ka,kb)` is the same as in `EUCLID(a,b)`, where `k` is some integer.
Hence, the bound is improved to 1 + log<sub>φ</sub>( b / gcd(a,b) ).